# Paid user registration in website with Alertpay

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment

In my website when user registers I want them to pay me with Alertpay at the time of registering. So the user register form will look like:

> Name
>
> Email
>
> Password
>
> Address
>
> Country
>
> Alertpay button for payment

I've coded my website in PHP. How can I integrate Alertpay to achieve this. Or should I add the Alertpay payment button after the user successfully registers with their details.

I really don't know the code that I've to add to integrate Alerpay. So I'm expecting some help on how to make paid user registration system.

Comment: You have to contact alert pay for their API, then you will have to integrate their API in your PHP for any payment solution.

Comment: here is the link for the API https://dev.alertpay.com/en/integration-tools/api.html

Comment: Thank you but how do I use it in PHP, I've no idea at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply call the file_get_contents function or fopen function to call the alertpay API URLs.

You will get some result which you will have to parse.

Along with the URL, you need to send some fields in query strings as well.

Comment: Can you please give me a short example and I'll accept this answer.

Comment: https://dev.alertpay.com/en/resources/sdks-and-sample-codes/cat_view/36-sdks-a-sample-code/41-php/44-api.html you can get example code here.